# Is There a CloudKit Functions?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm working on an app that will rely on data from NOAA and the EPA. I want to store the data centrally in a CloudKit database which the app can then query the public data from, but the problem lies in loading the data there. Is there something like a function or lambda for CloudKit that I could use to schedule a job to load data from NOAA and the EPA into the data store of CloudKit, which the app can then query? The only alternative I can think of is throwing a Mac mini in the corner of a closet with cron running Swift CLI programs which do it, would much rather have a function like functionality on CloudKit.

Comment: Would this question be a better fit at [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: No, CloudKit does not support such functions. You need an external app/program.